# rxjs v6 zip deprecated

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

my IDE (intelliJ) tells me that the zip function is deprecated.

Would you have a solution?

```js
zip(
  action$.pipe(successFetch("a", "list")),
  action$.pipe(successFetch("b", "list")),
  action$.pipe(successFetch("c", "list"))
)
```

its full use is as follows

```js
action$.pipe(
    zip(
      action$.pipe(successFetch("a", "list")),
      action$.pipe(successFetch("b", "list")),
      action$.pipe(successFetch("c", "list"))
    ),
    withLatestFrom(state$),
    mergeMap(([, state]) => {
      return of(...);
    }),
    startWith(
       fetchAction("a","list"),
       fetchAction("b","list"),
       fetchAction("c","list")
   )
  );
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

`zip` is not deprecated in `rxjs@6` but is in `rxjs@7`. It will be removed in version 8 and is replaced with [`zipWith`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/zipWith).

Your IDE is probably using the incorrect typings.